# Display choice options based on user

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I feel like my answer should be obvious, but I'm fairly new to Sharepoint and I have yet to stumble upon the solution. I've looked through the list of suggestions based on my title but I can't quite seem to find a duplicate to my particular issue.

Is there a way, on the New/Edit form, to populate a choice drop down based on which user is adding the item? Essentially, I have team leads who will be entering in information on the list, and will need to choose which agent on their team the item is for. I'd like the drop down list to only show those agents that are in their team.

Near as I can tell, I can create a second list that is essentially just a mapping of Agent to Team Lead. From there, I'm assuming I can pull that info into the primary Coaching list. Unfortunately, this is where I'm stuck, and no amount searching seems to yield a result, and I'm not entirely sure how to filter based on current user. I'm not even sure I'm asking the right question(s).

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to customizing the form using Designer?

Comment: Absolutely. In fact I fully anticipated I would have to. I'm only limited by OOTB functionality. I won't be able to install or apply solutions to the software that would enable this behavior to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is already a few month old let me explain how a solution might look like. Maybe this helps someone else:

If you're limited to OOTB functionality javascript is your friend, as you can alter the options based on all the information you can get using jsom. There are tools like [DFFS](http://spjsblog.com/dffs/) which can make it easier to start off. Using the 2nd list you're talking about you could fire a query using the current user to filter those list items and show only those options which get returned for that query.

Comment: I usually think of editing list item forms as something in between OOB functionality and full-on server-side dev functionality. I mean, the average SharePoint user is no more going to be able to call the CSOM (or use SPServices) than they would be to write a bit of C# code and upload that into their server.

Comment: I totally agree and like your answer, as it's something I didn't think of at all. However, people tend to expect too much regarding SharePoint and how you can enhance the user experience without any kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* that you can make this work by creating a Lookup field and then restricting access to different list items in the list you're referencing using SharePoint's built in security. There's a limit as to how many times you can do that on any one list, and a pretty low limit at that (the default if memory serves is 6), but it's a *possible* solution. The reason why I'm not 100% sure is that you're talking about selecting individual people and you can't do a lookup column with a Person field (because those Person objects are already lookups from the SiteUsers list), but depending on what your company's requirements are, this may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings of the list, so that you are able to create folders in the list.
Create a folder for each team.
Break the authorization settings per folder and give only the team lead access to the folder of his team.
Add the team members items in the appropriate team folders.